# How to sort a list based of values inside it's elements?

Tags: python, list

Knowing that the values inside the list num, num2 will change, the idea is to sort the output list, or the lists that form the output, based on the sorted num2.
This is the code:

```
letter = ['A','B','C','D','E']
num = [7,6,1,1,1]
num2 = [24000,20900,5250,4500,5000]
output = []

for i in range(len(letter)):
    output.append((letter[i], num[i], num2[i]))
```

Current Output:

```
[('A', 7, 24000), ('B', 6, 20900), ('C', 1, 5250), ('D', 1, 4500), ('E', 1, 5000)]
```

Expected Output:

```
[(’A’, 7, 24000), (’B’, 6, 20900), (’C’, 1, 5250), (’E’, 1, 5000), (’D’, 1, 4500)]
```

Comment: `sorted(zip(letter,num,num2),key=lambda x:x[2],reverse=True)` in one line you can format like this.

Comment: you can use both `lambda` function or `itemgetter` to sort a list of tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip` then sort:

```
output = sorted(zip(letter, num, num2), key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
print(*output)
```

Output:

```
[('A', 7, 24000), ('B', 6, 20900), ('C', 1, 5250), ('E', 1, 5000), ('D', 1, 4500)]
```

Comment: The expected output does not match yours. It appears they want all lists reordered in the same way.

Comment: @AmosBaker Thanks. I had it that way at fist but changed it because I misread the example output.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you could avoid the temporary assignment altogether as well.

```
[(x, y, z) for x, y, z in sorted(zip(letter, num, num2), key=lambda thus: thus[2], reverse=True)]
```

result:

```
[('A', 7, 24000), ('B', 6, 20900), ('C', 1, 5250), ('E', 1, 5000), ('D', 1, 4500)]
```